# PATH e opções do gfortran

Tags: fortran

Algumas opções do gfortran permitem incluir caminhos para bibliotecas e módulos do fortran:

```
$ gfortran -c <código fonte> [opções]
```

Dentre as funções tem-se o `-J<path file .mod>`,  que permite indicar os diretórios dos módulos, assim como `-I` e o `-L`.
A dúvida consiste se no gfortran é possível fazer uso de variáveis de ambiente e assim definir um *path* para a execução dos programas. Teria-se também outra forma de se fazer referência a `file.[90 or 95 or 03 or 08]`?